# xdg-mime not working for setting text/hmtl

Tags: settings

`xdg-mime query default 'text/html'`

output:

`userapp-Firefox-FFE3DY.desktop`

I try to set opera:

`xdg-mime default opera.desktop 'text/html'`

`xdg-mime query default 'text/html'`

output:

`userapp-Firefox-FFE3DY.desktop`

Notes;
`xdg-open "http://example.com"` opens Opera.

`xdg-mime default opera.desktop x-scheme-handler/https`
`xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https`
output
`userapp-Firefox-FFE3DY.desktop`

`update-desktop-database` did not work
neither did `update-alternatives`